# Intersection of the lists in a list (list of lists) in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, intersection

I have a list of lists, like follow:

```
list = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[3,5,6]]
```

I want to find the intersection of them in python 2.7, I mean

```
intersect_list = [3]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have any code, yet?

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried pairwise intersection between a result and every element of list, but I think it is not an optimal way, should I write it here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, don't use `list` as a variable name - it hides the built in class.

Next, this will do it

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[3,5,6]]
>>> set.intersection(*map(set,a))
{3}
```

The `map(set,a)` simply converts it to a list of sets. Then you just unpack the list and find the intersection.

If you really need the result as a list, just wrap the call with `list(...)`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection

Comment: You could use `set(a[0]).intersection(*a[1:])` which would avoid needing to convert most of the lists to sets.

Comment: You could do `set(m[0]).intersection(*m[1:])` for refusing of converting all the sublists to `set`.

Comment: Nifty use of the unpacking: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/

Comment: Yeah, but I just prefer the straightforward call to map. Seems cleaner and more intuitive. You need to understand unpacking either way

Comment: @DanD. Oh! Thanks.

Comment: @Kasramvd Thanks you too